# raspberry pi cannot log in with remote putty

Tags: raspberry-pi, putty

I'm pretty sure my Username and Password is correct. If I connect raspberry pi with monitor and keyboard, I'll be able to log in.

now, I connect raspberry pi and my desktop in the same network, both using cables. I use PUTTY to connect to raspberry pi, it keeps giving me error says my password is incorrect.
Is possible that PUTTY send a wrong password over the network?

thanks for any helps.

Comment: Can it be you have different keyboard layouts?

Comment: I don't think so. I used same keyboard. Now I reinstall raspberry pi. it seems now work fine.